# Cannot POST a XML string to a REST service using Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a REST service exposed via POST which consumes application/xml. I am trying to call it from Apache Camel Route. From Camel I am posting a XML string message.
This works correctly when I expose my REST service via POST and accepts application/json. But when I am trying to use applcation/xml, it is throwing the following error from Camel route:

```
org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking <<someURL>> with statusCode: 415
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.DefaultJettyHttpBinding.populateHttpOperationFailedException(DefaultJettyHttpBinding.java:183) ~[camel-jetty-common-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.DefaultJettyHttpBinding.populateResponse(DefaultJettyHttpBinding.java:71) ~[camel-jetty-common-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9.onResponseComplete(JettyContentExchange9.java:99) ~[camel-jetty9-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9$2.onComplete(JettyContentExchange9.java:251) ~[camel-jetty9-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:216) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:208) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:470) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseSuccess(HttpReceiver.java:416) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.messageComplete(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:316) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseFields(HttpParser.java:1171) ~[jetty-http-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1531) ~[jetty-http-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:172) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:135) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:73) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:133) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:155) ~[jetty-client-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281) ~[jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102) ~[jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) ~[jetty-io-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762) ~[jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680) ~[jetty-util-9.4.11.v20180605.jar:9.4.11.v20180605]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

Comment: Have you tried posting XML with PostMan or SOAPUI to the endpoint. 415 says unsupported type, it looks like XML is not accepted.

Comment: Hi, the call worked. the problem was I was setting the headers wrongly.